# Upload file size limited in live site

Tags: wordpress

I am building a wordpress website for my client. My client wants a 68MB video to be uploaded in there. But I can't able to upload it because it says that the allowed memory size is 32MB. how can I increase this size? I've bought the domain using godaddy.

Answer (score 0):

ensure that your php.ini is configured as needed

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 68M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 68M
```

Comment: I've searched for php.ini in my root folder in cpanel. I can't find any file named php.ini there

Comment: You can add those lines to the .htaccess file also

Comment: With the same syntax?

Comment: just without `=` like `upload_max_filesize xxM`